# Obtain Facebook users friend list?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

A programming test I have been given for an iOS developer intern position is asking me to fetch/retrieve a Facebook users friend list...and simply display it in a tableview.

My question is how do I do this, in an abstract sense? I googled around and it seems that this is no longer possible unless a users Facebook friends are also using the app. Isn't this pointless? And how on earth is this company expecting me to implement such functionality?

Hope someone can shed some insight...

Comment: You are correct since Graph API 2.0 its not possible to retrieve friends list unless friend too has authorised your app.

Comment: Do what’s possible, and explain to them what is _not_ possible any more …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can get the user's friends list by making a call to the following link.......https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/taggable_friends........... irrespective of whether your friends are using your app or not...it gives the full list of friends....hope this  helps